# 12.04 Ambiance dark side bar issue when clicking folder on desktop

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus, gtk3, ambiance

Concerning an updated custom ambiance theme: why is there no dark side bar when I click on a folder, like the home folder icon on the desktop, but the theme works as planned when I type `nautilus` in the terminal to open the home folder or when opening a folder up as root? Permissions issue perhaps?

Note: I am using Cinnamon instead of Unity and I noticed it uses the Nemo file manager instead of Nautilus and I suspected that it was causing me the grief. I uninstalled it and now am using Nautilus only as the file manager. I found this out when I typed: `sudo killall nemo` and the problem went away.

I'll see how this goes (and hopefully cinnamon doesn't care about it...)

Has anyone else had any issues with this?

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus became sluggish for me too (UB12.04), but no NEMO was running.

For me, removing and then reinstalling `nautilus` worked. Now it's lightning-fast.